# Query to move value from Columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I want to merge the data in third table as shown below,

**Table 1:**

```
User Id  Account1  Account 2  
-------  --------  ---------
Lucky    Twitter   Facebook  
Happy    Orkut     GooglePlus
```

**Table 2**

```
User Id  AccountStatus 
-------  ------------- 
Lucky    Active
```

I want the result as:

```
UserId   Account  
------   --------
Lucky    Twitter  
Lucky    Facebook
```

Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Just `unpivot` the data to get the result in format

using `CROSS APPLY` operator

```
SELECT [user id], 
       account 
FROM   table1 A 
       CROSS apply (VALUES (account1), 
                           (account2)) cs(account) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   table2 B 
               WHERE  A.[user id] = B.[user id]
                 AND  B.AccountStatus = 'Active')
```

or use `UNION ALL` to `unpivot` the data

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT [user id], 
               account1  as account
        FROM   table1 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT [user id], 
               account2 
        FROM   table1) A 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   table2 B 
               WHERE  A.[user id] = B.[user id]
                 AND  B.AccountStatus = 'Active')
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has native support for `UNPIVOT`, so you should use it:

```
SELECT UserI
FROM
(
    SELECT A.UserId, Account1, Account2
    FROM Account A
        JOIN AccountStatus S ON S.UserId = A.UserId
    WHERE S.AccountStatus = 'Active'
) AS acc
UNPIVOT 
(
   Account FOR Acc IN (Account1, Account2)
) AS up;
```

I don't know if it is faster, but it allows you to easily extend your account types just by adding columns in two places (`SELECT` and within `UNPIVOT`).

Answer (score 1):

```
; With cteActiveAccount As(
   Select UserId
   From Table2 where AccountStatus = 'Active'
 )
, cteAccountFilterdOnes As(
  Select r.UserId
         r.Account1 as Account 
  from Table1 r
  inner join cteActiveAccount c on
      r.UserId = c.UserId
  union all
  Select r.UserId
         r.Account2 as Account 
  from Table1 r
  inner join cteActiveAccount c on
      r.UserId = c.UserId
  )
```

select * from cteAccountFilterdOnes